# Getting offline_access to work with Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am using Facebooker with Rails to connect my application to Facebook.  I can direct the user through the authorization process and through the process of granting offline access to my application.

How do I actually go about accessing the information offline?  Is there a way to request a session_key that does not expire that I can use at a later point, so long as the user has not revoked the permissions for my application on Facebook?

Any help greatly appreciated.  Advice need not be rails specific.

Answer (score 2):

Once you ask for, and are granted, offline access the session key you get in the HTTP POST parameters from Facebook (fb_sig_session_key) will have no expiry.

You can check you have such a key by checking the fb_sig_expires parameter, if this is "0" then the session key has no expiry.

If you have an auth_token then you can call getSession to get the session key  and check the expires field:

```
var auth = _auth.getSession(AuthToken);
string sessionKey = auth.session_key;
long uid = auth.uid;
bool expires = auth.expires > 0;
```

Comment: Hi Mark - thanks for the info.  Do you know if the session key changes after you are granted offline access?  In Facebooker, the session key I get back seems to be the same as the one I started with, and it has an expiration.

Matt

Answer (score 1):

I just made a [tutorial](http://modelix.net/2009/09/facebook-connect-working-with-offline-users-data-access/) on my blog with a step by step explanation on how to access offline user's data. It assumes you're working with RoR and the Facebooker plugin.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [apparently](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=29517), granting "offline_access" still gives you (and will continue doing so) an infinite session key. just save this special key and use it in your call to Status.get etc. see [here](http://wiki.horde.org/Doc/Dev/Horde_Service_Facebook#toc3) for a (PHP) code example.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/New_Design_User_Login :

> many API calls no longer require
>   session keys

so if your app is granted offline_access, you can use API calls [listed here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/New_Design_Platform_Changes#Changes_to_Session_Keys) without a session_key.

> And we're changing more methods so you
>   won't need a session key to do
>   something when the user is offline,
>   like send a notification.

Comment: Thanks for the information on functions not requiring a session key.  Unfortunately the methods I need require a session_key that does not expire.

Comment: The User.getSession method.  I am trying to retrieve their stream of status updates.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I need to review the facebooker code, as the session key I am getting after offline access is granted still has an expiration date.  I suspect that facebook issues a new session key once offline access has been granted and facebooker is not updating it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get offline access permission from a user, the trick is to call with a `filter_key` parameter of 'network'.

In PHP, it is:

```
$feed = $facebook->api_client->stream_get($uid, '', '', '', 20, 'network', '');
```

Try it, it works....