# Retrieving friend's likes from the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, api

Howdy- I have been tooling around with the Facebook Graph API and successfully retrieved back a list of my likes, and a list of my friends (once I authenticated using OAuth). But what I really want to achieve is pulling back my friend's likes. When I try and do that, obviously using the same URL that I use to pull back my own likes but subbing the friend's user id for "me", I don't get anything back, unless they have installed the app as well. Then I get them no problem. To be clear, I can only see the likes of friends who have installed my application. So clearly I am running into a security/rights issue of some sort.

I could see where this would be the case; you simply aren't allowed to see your friend's likes unless they have installed the same app. Fair enough, but then how is blekko.com doing it? I even tried using FQL without much luck. I suspect I am missing something totally obvious. Anyone had any luck with this? Maybe with the Javascript API or one of the other access methods? Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Your application needs the permission "friends_likes".

Check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions for more info on the different permissions.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059640/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step/3249758#3249758) might help if you're having trouble with the authentication / permission request process.