# Facebook App: Where do i put offline_access request?

Tags: php, facebook

I need my app to request the offline_access permission (detailed [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)), but as ever I'm baffled by the Facebook documentations.

It says I need a comma separated list of my permission demands, like `'publish_stream,offline_access'` etc

**where do i put this list in the interface below????**

[image]

Comment: can you show us your front-end code (where you ask the user to login)? both answers are correct but based on your code you might want to use a different approach

Comment: it's a single user app, it requires the user to be logged in. Think i found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059640/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step will update this post once i have thoroughly tested that solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used with the API, as follows

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    'cookie' => false,
));

$facebook_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'next' => '',
    'cancel_url' => '',
    'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update'
));
```

Where `$facebook_login_url` is the URL tha the user needs to follow to grant you access.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with that interface. You need to set `scope` parameter when redirecting user to facebook.

```
x=y&scope=email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_photos,publish_stream,offline_access
```

Answer (score 0):

First define which permissions you will need:

```
$par['req_perms'] = "friends_about_me,friends_education_history,friends_likes,friends_interests,friends_location,friends_religion_politics,
     friends_work_history,publish_stream,friends_activities,friends_events,
    friends_hometown,friends_location,user_interests,user_likes,user_events,
    user_about_me,user_status,user_work_history,read_requests,read_stream,offline_access,user_religion_politics,email,user_groups";
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($par);
```

Then, check if the user has already subscribed to app:

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
if ( is_null($session) ) {
    // no he is not
    //send him to permissions page
    header( "Location: $loginUrl" );
}
else {
    //yes, he is already subscribed, or subscribed just now
    echo "<p>everything is ok";
    // write your code here
    }
```