# Publishing comments on my Facebook app profil

Tags: oauth, facebook

My server is able to publish posts on my Facebook app wall. But I would like to publish comments on user writing on the wall...  When trying to post a comment to a given post ID I always get the following:

`{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"}}`

However I gave all possible authorization as a test user to this app.
Any suggestion ?

**Addition**.

I also tried to use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059640/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step)
The URL I'm using looks like this

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$comment['id'].'/comments?'.$access_token)`

Now I get the following message

`{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#100) Invalid fbid."}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found my own solution, but for the record since some people my stumble like me :

1. first you need to apply this [awesome authentification method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059640/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step)
2. need to call facebook with the following

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '&message=hello World');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$post['id'].'/comments?'.$access_token);`

Answer (score 0):

If you can give some code, this would help. however, this is resulted usually from 3 reasons:

1. The user hasn't installed your app.
2. You didn't specify a **VALID** OAuth access token  for this session with the query you performed.
3. You don't have the `publish_stream` from the user, [which you need to publish.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#publishing)-You said you have this, but did you specify this specific permission?

Comment: Since I'm testing, the only user is my personnal facebook profile. As a user I gave the authorization to publish on my stream. However want I want to achieve is to comment the applications profile wall. I have been able to put a post on the app wall, but am not not able to post a comment to a post (If I'm clear).

Answer (score 0):

My dear take the permission of publish_stream from the user. the error is just because of that. you can take publish stream like this

```
<fb:login-button perms="publish_stream" autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: see above. I don't want to publish on the user wall, I want to publish a comment on my own application wall.