# Facebook API - Authenticate Specific User..?

Tags: php, facebook, api, oauth

I'm connecting to Facebook API via the simple examples posted in the Facebook Developers' Documentation

```
$code = $_GET["code"];
    if(empty($code)) {
        // Really long scope, but I've tested it, and there aren't any errors here.
        $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . 
        "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . 
        '&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream,read_mailbox,read_requests,create_event,
        manage_pages,publish_checkins,manage_friendlists,read_friendlists,user_about_me,
        user_activities,user_birthday,user_checkins,user_education_history,user_events,
        user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photo_video_tags,
        user_photos,user_relationship_details,user_relationships,user_religion_politics,
        user_status,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history';

    echo "<script> window.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>";
}
```

I then use the callback to acquire the access token and run a check to see if the user is already in my database. However, I've noticed that if I log in to a different Facebook account and use the login stored in my database to log the user in, when it authenticates, it's for the currently logged in Facebook user.

My question is: Is there a way to alter the above authentication code to use the Facebook user id stored in my database and authenticate that user specifically.

For example, if the user with an active Facebook session is not the user logging in to my site, it would end the current session (log out of Facebook) and request the user to log in to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to authenticate a user in Facebook api, online and offline. When you are logged in to Facebook with one user and you want to access another, you are in fact accessing the other user in offline mode. For this you need the offline access permission.
After you have this permission, you can follow the procedure in this question:
[Facebook offline access step-by-step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059640/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step)

**A side note:** From my experience, people really don't like to give the offline_access permission. Only ask for this if you really really need it, and understand that this might limit the amount of users who will use the app. Just my two cents.