# Post to facebook wall without logging in

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I want to post messages, links, etc. into facebook wall without logging in.

For example, I have a blog site, when I submit/post a blog, the url for that blog will automatically post on facebook.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should specify some language, since Facebook has got many SDKs for different languages.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible, as long as you have a valid authorization token to use with Facebook (this means, it is not possible if the user hasn't authorized your application). For this, though, you require "offline_access" within the token's permissions. [More about the topic on Facebook's documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Please note that this behavior is not exactly... uhm, encouraged by Facebook, thus there isn't much documentation on how to do it.
You should also remember that you must have a way to store your access token, since requesting it again would require user input, as well as some kind of way to get one again, for it expires after some time (it is long-lived, though).

Comment: A practical example can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059640/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough great answer given already I would share this post: http://eagerfish.eu/using-facebook-off-line-access-to-post-on-users-wall/. It is short explanation how to post on your/others wall without signing in. It uses offline_access permission pointed out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are a bit misleading!
You **don't** need the `offline_access` permission to post content to Facebook. Only the `publish_stream` permission is needed.

Even if no user login is required. Once the user authorize your app with the `publish_stream` permission, you can start posting content on his behalf *without* the need of him to login!

I described this [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-a-message-on-the-user-wall-using-facebook-graph-api/33/). I'll expand the post to provide a more complete code soon.

Comment: He asks for no need to authenticate. This means that unless he's previously logged into Facebook, he would be asked for authentication. That being said, having offline_access permission is more than necessary, along with publish_stream (which I missed).

Comment: as I said, once the user authorize your app with the publish stream permission. You can post **without** him being online!

Answer (score 0):

Both of these permissions 
`offline_access` and `publish_streams` have been removed,
link here

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/
```