# How can I read a Facebook fan page with the Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

A few more specifics:

We have a good amount of fans on my restaurant's page, but we'd like to run our own website as well, with the same content (specials, etc.,) as Facebook.

With that said, we'd like to continue posting our daily specials on Facebook, as about 3,000 people see those posts and we bring in a good amount of business from there.

I have a small PHP script I've written that can pull the posts off of the wall, verify who wrote them and look for a small #hashtag to verify that I want it posted on the main page of our website.

However, periodically my access token expires and, therefore, I suspect I'm not going about this correctly.

Does anyone have a good, reliable way to read posts from a Facebook fan page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing Access Token expiry time with offline_access permission.

Facebook Permissions page mentions about offline_access;

Enables your application to perform authorized requests on behalf of the user at any time. By default, most access tokens expire after a short time period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user when the are actively using the application. This permission makes the access token returned by our OAuth endpoint long-lived.

Comment: Some easy instructions to get offline_access: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059640/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step