# Getting User Feed From Facebook Without User Login

Tags: facebook, feed

we are working on a web site that getting users' friends and users' feeds. Users can register via facebook connect. but we want to take user's feeds at any time. is that possible ? can we take feed information from facebook without user login.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to take the permission from user for **[offline_access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617043/getting-offline-access-to-work-with-facebook)**, only then you can get his feeds.

Answer (score 0):

This would be very bad. There are users that have their feed on public, but generally, the user has to give explicit confirmation to allow you to use their feed.

Comment: i know that user must give permission to app. But if user gives permission, is that possible?