# Do I need "offline_access" permission if I request publish_stream?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-like

For Facebook, I requested **email and publish_stream**.

I got their access_token. yay!

Now....when I try to send a POST to their wall (/feed), I get this message:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1315342800. The current unix time is 1315363038."}}
```

Why? Do I need offline_access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. From Facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/):

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission,
>   you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, **without
>   requiring offline_access**.

To publish to the users feed after their short lived token expires, send over an access token in this format:

```
appid|appsecret
```

This token format is taken from the PHP SDK source code. In this case you won't be able to use /me/feed so you would need to POST to /userid/feed

Comment: The definition for the application access token is as follows: "The application access token, useful for gathering public information about users and applications." It does not say that you can publish to stream.

Comment: Are you using OAuth 2.0 and Facebook PHP SDK's latest version? Thanks a lot by the way -appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you request `offline_access` you get a token that expires after a set amount of time.

So yes, if you're not making the API request (POST) within a short amount of time of requesting the token, you need that.